# Can I disable Apple ID two-factor authentication after enabling it for the second time?

Tags: ios, icloud, apple-id, two-factor-authentication

I previously enabled 2FA for my Apple ID and disabled it within the two-week window.  If I re-enable it, will I get another two weeks to disable it?

The reason I'm asking is that I want to enable Messages in iCloud to sync some messages between devices, but when that's finished I want to disable Messages in iCloud and download the synced set of messages to each device.  Then I want to turn 2FA off again.

Here is my other related question about passcodes and 2FA:

[Does Apple ID two-factor authentication force iOS device passcode / touch ID / face ID?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428012/does-apple-id-two-factor-authentication-force-ios-device-passcode-touch-id-f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded my apple ID to 2FA.  There is no option to disable it on appleid.apple.com.  Initially it was upgraded to two-step verification because I did not have a passcode enabled.  There was the option to disable two-step verification.  However, once I enabled a passcode and upgraded to 2FA, there was no longer an option to disable 2FA.

In the end I'm okay with this outcome because despite being stuck with 2FA, I still don't have to keep a passcode enabled, which was my primary concern.