# Does Apple ID two-factor authentication force iOS device passcode / touch ID / face ID?

Tags: ios, icloud, apple-id, password, two-factor-authentication

If I have 2FA enabled for an Apple ID, am I required to use a passcode, touch ID, or face ID on iOS devices logged in to that ID?

In my particular case, I want to enable 2FA so that I can sync messages via Messages in iCloud.  There is a chance I might not be able to disable 2FA again since I already did that in the past, so I want to be clear about the consequences ahead of time.  Ultimately, I don't want a passcode at all times on every device.

Comment: Which practical problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Basically risk assessment.  I am trying to find out the consequences of enabling 2FA in case I get locked in to it.  I don't want to have a passcode on some devices.  I was previously able to disable 2FA after two weeks, but I don't know if I can do that a second time for the same ID.  I asked a separate question about this.  I want to enable 2FA so that I can sync messages between devices with iCloud.  When they are synced I want to disable Messages in iCloud and download them all to individual devices and then turn off 2FA.  If needed I can experiment to find out the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I just confirmed you can disable your password. I did not do it, but the message that appears tells me that you lose Apple Pay, and you won't be able to reset your Apple ID credentials. It does not say I cannot remove it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for checking and responding to a closed question.  I subsequently found this guideline on Apple's [support website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915#setup): "Use a device passcode on all your devices." That also sounds like it's optional.  I'll accept this as an answer if this question gets reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and upgraded.  A passcode is not mandatory once 2FA is enabled.

Upgrading to 2FA on appleid.apple.com with no passcode enabled actually upgrades to the weaker two-step verification.  There is an option to turn this off.  This two-step verification security can also be seen under Apple ID->Password & Security on iOS.

On that settings page, there is also a button to upgrade account security, which says that a passcode must be enabled when tapped.  Enabling a passcode does allow the upgrade to 2FA.  However, once upgraded, the passcode can be disabled without problems.

Ezekiel comments that you might lose Apple Pay and the ability to reset Apple ID credentials.  I did not have Apple Pay set up.  I also did not receive a warning about Apple ID credentials.